Are "scalar field" and "scalar-valued function" synonymous?
Is a "scalar field" synonymous with a "scalar-valued function"? If not, is one a sub-type of the other; in what way? It seems that scalar fields must be continuous and differentiable scalar-valued functions, but this is just my intuition -- I have not read this as a requirement anywhere.

In what context have you seen scalar field? If as I suspect it was in physics that's important to note, so we don't mix up their field with our field.

@J.G.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field is where I read up on it. I work in computer science. I usually know what I want to construct, but I often do not know what the right terminology is. So the "context" is in my head and then I need to find out how to call those things.

Thanks for that. I'd say scalar fields in that sense are synonymous with scalar functions. They don't have to be continuous, but requirements such as continuity or differentiability may be imposed by various considerations in certain fields of interest.

The Dirichlet function is a scalar function and it's discontinuous and non-differentiable everywhere.

It is difficult to answer either yes or no to this question. Let me say some more precise things:

Neither of these are standard terminology in mathematics. "Scalar field" is physics terminology; I have no idea in what context people say "scalar-valued function." If a mathematician wanted to refer to a scalar-valued function they'd just say "let $f : X \to K$ be a function" where $K$ is the field (this is an unrelated use of the term "field"!) of scalars.

It would be misleading to say that there is no difference because, for example, it is not true that "vector field" (which is standard terminology in mathematics) is synonymous with "vector-valued function." The reason is that a vector-valued function takes values in a fixed vector space $V$, whereas a vector field takes values in the tangent bundle, which is a varying family $T_x$ of vector spaces.

In the context of quantum field theory, for example when physicists say that the Higgs field is a scalar field, the use of the term "scalar field" carries more information and context than just that it is a scalar-valued function, because "fields" in quantum field theory have specified behaviors with respect to symmetries, and "scalar field" is a name for a specific such behavior with respect to symmetry. In this context there's also an ambiguity in whether "field" refers to a classical field or a quantum field; the Higgs field is a quantum field, for example.


Continuity or differentiability is not really the key point; physicists don't usually bother to specify things like that, and again, neither of these are standard terminology in mathematics so I couldn't point you to completely precise definitions anyway. In mathematics if we wanted to be precise we'd say "let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function" or more generally a $C^k$ function for some $k$ (if $X$ is a manifold of the appropriate type).
Edit: I poked around a little more and the Higgs field is not even a scalar-valued function, not even classically! It appears to take values in $\mathbb{C}^2$, so it is actually two complex-valued functions, or four real-valued functions. So "scalar field" here really is referring to symmetry and not to the number of parameters.
